# HTTP GET data from function in script in head not available in body after calling function

Tags: javascript, html, get

I have a script in HTML page head that declares a function to make a get requests for JSON data and passes it to element’s innerHTML.

function called on page load.

Script in head correctly gets JSON data and populates elements innerHTML.

I would like to cross-fade loop between the 2 bits of JSON data.

Script in body tries to get element’s innerHTML and create array to use as input to cross fade loop.

Element’s innerHTML variable comes back empty.

The cross-fade loop script works if strings are declared in array.

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/50623uof/)

How can I get the JSON values into the text cycle?

```
    <script>
        var intervalID = window.setInterval(insertText, 2000);

        function insertText(){

            const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            const url = "https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=XXBTZUSD";

            Http.open("GET", url);
            Http.send();

            Http.onreadystatechange=(e)=>{
                const price = Http.responseText
                const priceJson = JSON.parse(price);
                var priceJsonBtc = priceJson.result.XXBTZUSD.c[0];
                var btc = parseFloat(priceJsonBtc)
                var btcp = btc.toFixed(2)
                console.log(btcp);
                document.getElementById("priceUsd").innerHTML = "$" + btcp + " USD";
                const usdp = btcp
                }

            const HttpGbp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            const urlGbp = "https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=XXBTZGBP";

            HttpGbp.open("GET", urlGbp);
            HttpGbp.send();

            HttpGbp.onreadystatechange=(e)=>{
                const priceGbp = HttpGbp.responseText
                const priceJsonGbp = JSON.parse(priceGbp);
                var priceJsonBtcGbp = priceJsonGbp.result.XXBTZGBP.c[0];
                var btcGbp = parseFloat(priceJsonBtcGbp)
                var btcpGbp = btcGbp.toFixed(2)
                console.log(btcpGbp);
                document.getElementById("priceGbp").innerHTML = "£" + btcpGbp + " GBP";
                const gbpp = btcpGbp
                }                
            }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload=insertText()>
<h1 id="priceUsd"></h1>
<h1 id="priceGbp"></h1>
<h1 id="changer">£ GBP</h1>
<script>

    var usd = document.getElementById("priceUsd").innerHTML;
    var gbp = document.getElementById("priceGbp").innerHTML;

/* This does not work */
    /* var words = [usd, gbp]; */

/* This does work */
    var words = ["£ GBP", "$ USD"];
        var i = 0;
        var text = "BTC";
        function _getChangedText() {
          i = (i + 1) % words.length;
          return text.replace(/BTC/, words[i]);
        }
        function _changeText() {
          var txt = _getChangedText();
            var d = document.getElementById("changer")
            d.className = "fadeOut";
            setTimeout(function(){
             d.className = "";
            document.getElementById("changer").innerHTML = txt;
        }, 900);
        }
        setInterval("_changeText()", 1000);
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved with setInterval to delay pulling HTML elements before they had been updated:

```
var intervalID = window.setInterval(updateText, 1500);
function updateText() {
    var usd = document.getElementById("price").innerHTML
    var gbp = document.getElementById("priceGbp").innerHTML
    words = [usd, gbp]
    }

var i = 0;
var text = "BTC";
    function _getChangedText() {
          i = (i + 1) % words.length;
          return text.replace(/BTC/, words[i]);
        }
    function _changeText() {
          var txt = _getChangedText();
            var d = document.getElementById("changer")
            d.className = "fadeOut";
            setTimeout(function(){
             d.className = "";
            document.getElementById("changer").innerHTML = txt;
        }, 800);
    }setInterval("_changeText()", 3000)
```